# Programmatically capturing video with the FFmpeg libaries (not the libav fork) with variable frame rate in c++

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, video-capture

I am working on a simulator in c++ and OpenGL and I wanted to add some video capture capabilities (cross platform would be a requirement here). I decided to work with FFmpeg since I can directly put my rendered frames into a video. So far so good, but in a 3D rendering engine you are usually far from having a constant frame rate and I think that it is not a good idea to go constant there. Therefore I am trying to figure out how to capture a variable frame rate video with FFmpeg or how to get from my variable frame rate of the simulator to a constant frame rate for the video in FFmpeg. Can anybody help me out here? How are videos usually captured in variable frame rate environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable frame rate is mostly an issue in the muxing stage, since your container (e.g. good ol' AVI) might not support VFR. As long as you're muxing into a format that supports per-frame timestamps, you should be OK. Good examples of this are mkv (matroska) or mp4. Then, as long as the AVPacket.dts is set correctly during encoding/muxing, you should be fine and your video should be VFR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will not be adding sound to the video for the moment, therefore the muxing part will not be a tough thing. I looked into the FFmpeg examples but I could not find one that was doing something in the direction of timestamping and encoding a video. Is there one that I have not seen yet?

Comment: Probably not. Most examples are quite a bit simpler than that. In your frame capture code, just make sure your timestamps are as precise as possible. Then use these timestamps to set the AVPacket.pts values of the encoded frames when you're writing them using the VFR-capable muxer. That's all, it should work just naturally after that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I realized that the timestamps have to be measured in the time base we set. And the time base as far as I understand is dependent on the framerate we set in the setup. So I tried to comment the time base setting and tried to use a pure timestamp (milliseconds or seconds passed), but it says that I have to set the framerate. What framerate should be set there or how can I avoid setting it? I am using mp4 as the container.

Comment: The frame rate and time base are in separate fields. The codec time base is in AVStream->codec->time_base, and the average frame rate (which is what movenc.c uses) is in AVStream->avg_frame_rate. Also note that the default timebase for AVPacket.pts/fts is AV_TIME_BASE (milliseconds).